# Improving a MySQL Delete Query when using COUNT

Tags: mysql, count, sql-delete

I found that the following query is causing some bottleneck (the execution time takes more than 40 seconds!)

```
DELETE FROM doctors 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(loc_id) 
       FROM locations 
       WHERE locations.loc_doctor = doctors.doc_id) = 0 AND 
       doctors.doc_user = $myVar
```

I guess the problem lies in the `(SELECT COUNT(loc_id) FROM locations WHERE locations.loc_doctor = doctors.doc_id) = 0` section, am I right?
Is there a way to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a little bit faster:

```
DELETE FROM doctors WHERE doctors.doc_user = $myVar AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM locations WHERE locations.loc_doctor = doctors.doc_id LIMIT 1)
```

As your counting for 0 is actually a `NOT EXISTS` check. You should also consider an index for locations.loc_doctor column (if you don't have one already).

Comment: yeah thats true, no need to check for 0.

Comment: It works VERY faster! :-) Thanks, I didn't knew the NOT EXISTS option!

Comment: LIMIT 1 is implicitly used when doing a NOT EXISTS search. Also it seems to not be faster than tyomitch's answer. See this link: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

I'd propose deleting from outer join:

```
DELETE doctors
FROM doctors LEFT JOIN locations
   ON locations.loc_doctor = doctors.doc_id
WHERE locations.loc_id IS NULL
AND doctors.doc_user = $myVar
```

Comment: @QuadroQ http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: thank you for the documentation link, that convinced me ! It's a great ideea you've presented here!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add **limit** to @tpeczek answer.

```
DELETE FROM doctors WHERE doctors.doc_user = $myVar AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM locations WHERE locations.loc_doctor = doctors.doc_id limit 1)
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1` is implicitly used when doing a `NOT EXISTS` search. Also here's a nice article about comparing NOT EXISTS vs LEFT JOIN/IS NULL... http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/